# Horizontal Raster Stretch Legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, legend

Using a blog page on [Raster enhancement: The horizontal legend](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/imagery/raster-enhancement-the-horizontal-legend/) I have displayed my legend of a raster legend horizontally. However I have not been able to format the labels to align directly beneath the tick marks as shown below. The second label is shifted to the right e.g. 3, 2, etc.

[image]

I have adjusted the Layout Gap pt sizes in the properties but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens, but here is one (not ideal) fix:

Right-click your legend > Convert to Graphics. Right-click and select Ungroup repeatedly until your text labels are isolated. Drag the labels to the desired location.

This is not an ideal solution because the legend is not really a legend anymore; it's just a capture of the legend at that moment and will not update if you change the colors or range of your raster symbology.